# Magento: Display custom product attribute in admin Items ordered block

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, adminhtml

I am trying to display my custom attribute value on admin order - Items Ordered block. It will show points earned for each product just like as it shows `SKU` and other information. The attribute value is saved in `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item` tables.

[image]

**Namespace/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View/Items/Renderer/Default.phtml**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Items_Renderer_Default extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Items_Renderer_Default
{

}

?>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/design/design/layout/namespace/modulename.xml**

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_items">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type>
                <block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block>
                <template>namespace/modulename/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/namespace/modulename/sales/order/view/items/rederer/default.phtml**

```
    <?php $finalPointsEarned = ($_item->getCustomerProductPoints() * $_item->getQtyOrdered()); ?>
    <div class="product-cart-sku">
        <span style="color: #d4af37; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $this->__('Points Earned:'); ?>
            <?php echo $finalPointsEarned ?>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Executing above code gives below exception

```
Invalid method Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Item_Renderer_Default::addColumnRender(Array
(
    [0] => qty
    [1] => adminhtml/sales_items_column_qty
    [2] => sales/items/column/qty.phtml
)
)
```

Changing `<adminhtml_sales_order_view>` to `<sales_order_view>` does not give any output and custom prod attribute is not displayed.

**Attempt Two:**

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_items"> 
            <action method="addColumnRender">
                <column>NORTH FACE</column>
                <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
                <template>modulename/sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference> 
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

added my custom code in `name.phtml`, still no output.

1. How do I display the value of custom product attribute on Items
   ordered block ?
2. How do I display the same value of admin Invoice order details page ?
3. Is above, the best practice/method to display custom attribute on admin order/invoice/refund pages just like it displays `SKU`, `Size` and other values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most efficient way is to create a custom theme for a store admin, copy-paste the requested template in there and rewrite the output the way you want to have it.

Thus you will be able to fully customize it. Also, this approach will lower the risk of getting errors and provide you with the ability to customize any templates (including invoices, credit memos, etc.)

Have a look:

- Set a custom theme: (can be done in `app/etc/local` xml or in your extension config settings):

[image: Image1]

- Copy the template you need:

[image: Image 2]

- Adjust it as you need:

[image: Image 3]

- And get the result you want:

[image: Image 4]

Note that the custom attribute is usually entered via get method. If you are having any trouble with that, just check if it exists for the chosen item in the database. In the `sales_flat_order_item` table 
find all the items  related to the chosen order and make sure that it has the value, different from `null`. This is how it worked in my case:

[image: Image 5]
[image: Image 6]
[image: Image 7]

Comment: `sales_flat_order_item` table will show custom attribute values on order info page. Will the same work when Invoice is created in admin and on customer invoice on frontend ?

Comment: to pick up this data from the invoice, the attribute should refer to sales_flat_invoice_item. 

Alternatively, you get an order item from your invoice, and then get the value of the attribute there.

Comment: Suppose, I have not used `<sales_convert_quote_item>
                <customer_product_points>
                    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                    <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
                    <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
                    <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
                </customer_product_points>
            </sales_convert_quote_item>` to convert custom attributes to respective table. How do I show the value on frontend invoice ? Order item is not showing custom attribute value. Or do I need to use fieldsets to insert value into tables ?

Comment: If you don't have these attributes in any of the used entities, you need to get a quote item object from these entities (you can find a quote item id in any order item). Next, you can use it to acquire necessary attribute values.